# Need Help Locating Winforms-compatible Custom Tooltip Control

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

I think this is a very smart control, does winForms have such a thing?

Answer (score 3):

Devexpress has a free **ToolTipController** class (as well as ErrorProvider and HintController classes) which you can get here: https://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/NetOffer/ which provides exactly what you want. I use it on daily basis. You can simply drop a textbox onto the form and set its tooltip, tooltipcontroller, and tooltipicon properties as you wish (also you can use the validation event to display error messages as tooltips).

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [`ToolTip` component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx).

Comment: That's not a standard tooltip, is it?  Tooltips are on mouse-hover - that's a validation popup.

Comment: @Dan: You can show a tooltip manually; if there's an error, call `Show`.

Answer (score 0):

No, not out of the box. There is a tooltip but it doesn't look like the one you show.

But you could make it by creating a custom control.

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing I can think of is the [Error Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682136/c-winforms-errorprovider-control) control

Answer (score 0):

there is an error provider in winforms to do this but if you want to display like this you can use Tooltip

// Create the ToolTip and associate with the Form container.
         ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();

```
     // Set up the delays for the ToolTip.
     toolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
     toolTip1.InitialDelay = 1000;
     toolTip1.ReshowDelay = 500;
     // Force the ToolTip text to be displayed whether or not the form is active.
     toolTip1.ShowAlways = true;

     // Set up the ToolTip text for the Button .
     toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.button1, "My button1");
```

MSDN reference