# Powershell use ErrorProvider value for final form validation

Tags: winforms, powershell, errorprovider

With Powershell I have a Windows form, dynamically generating several text boxes. I use a validation on each textbox, then use an ErrorProvider to alert if the validation fails.

This is working fine for displaying the error '!' notification. Is there a way to check how many errors are left?

My pseudo-code would say:

1. On 'OK' click
2. Loop though each TextBox
3. Validate each TextBox
4. Error if fail / Clear error if pass
5. Return
6. If there are no more errors, close the form

Or do I need to maintain a separate logic to see when the errors have been rectified? *(The ErrorProvider check below is just a placeholder, I have no idea what to put there!)*

```
$ButtonOK.Add_Click({

    $objectList | where {$_ -is [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox] } | foreach-object {

    Validate-Input $_

    }

    if ($ErrorProvider -eq $null) { #This is where I'm stuck
        $Form.Close()
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So judging from the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682136/c-sharp-winforms-errorprovider-control?rq=1) there is no built in way to reference the amount of errors remaining. Taking the advice of that thread and porting it to Powershell I implemented the following:

1. Define a hash table to store the error state for each object
2. When setting or clearing an error use the following:

   **Set an error:**
   $errTable.set_item("$($curTB.name)","1")

   **Clearing an error:**
   $errTable.remove("$($curTB.name)")
3. Use the following code in the 'add_click' section:

   If ($errTable.count -le "0") {
       $form.close()
   }

Seems to work well and be pretty shorthand.