# Iterate through Controls to find errorProviders c# WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, errorprovider

**Overview of function.**

I have this `SaveDetails` function within a `WinForm`, which iterates through all of the `controls`, to determine whether any `errorProviders` have been flagged in the `form` during the users input. If the function `returns true`,
all of my `TextBoxes` values need to be stored in my private fields, and display a messsagebox and close the form.

// For about 15 textBoxes, Could this be achieved also by looping? As this looks very cumbersome.

```cs
title = cmb_Title.Text;
```

If `returns false` and an `errorProvider` has been found in the iteration, it needs to display an error message for the user, clear private fields and give the user chance to re-enter details, however not clear textBoxes!!

**Issue**:

the loop iterates through everything, all of the controls regardless if it has found an `errorProvider`. How can I stop this to just flag when just one has been found? This function is also in a `clickEvent`.

**Code**

```cs
isValid = true;
foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
{
    if (errorProvider1.GetError(c).Length > 0)
    {
        isValid = false;
        MessageBox.Show("invalid entry, please revisit the form before proceding");
    }
}
if (isValid)
{
    title = cmb_Title.Text;
    surName = txt_SurName.Text;
    dateOfBirth = dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString();

    MessageBox.Show("Indi Form Saved");
    Hide();
}
```

Comment: It never makes any sense to use more than one ErrorProvider for a form.  One is enough to provide icons and tooltips for all of the controls.  You'll never have any trouble finding that one provider back of course.  If you want to use ErrorProvider to *also* validate the entire form then [consider this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2682478/17034).

Answer (score 0):

you can shorten it using only `TextBox` controls and Linq.

Something like this:

```
List<TextBox> textBoxes = panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
if (textBoxes.Any(tb => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorProvider1.GetError(tb))))
    MessageBox.Show("invalid entry, please revisit the form before proceding");
```

If you don't want to check only `TextBox` controls but all controls in `panel1`, you can still use Linq to simplify your code.

```
var controlsList = panel1.Controls.Cast<Control>().ToList();
if (controlsList.Any(tb => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorProvider1.GetError(tb))))
    MessageBox.Show("invalid entry, please revisit the form before proceding");
```