# incrementing errorProvider in a validation loop

Tags: c#

*I have 5 error provider controls in my form which correspond to 5 text boxes, I am trying to loop through each text box and perform some validation on it such as if the text box is empty*.

If a textbox is empty I would like the corresponding error provider control to display an error message, however **I am having trouble when it comes to how to increment the errorprovider,** **such as errorProvider[count] where count would get incremented after each validation loop**.

```
 private void ValidateForm(){
    int count = 1;
    foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()){
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text)){
           errorProvider1.SetError(tb, "Please enter a value");
           //errorProvider[count].SetError(tb, "Please enter a value");
        }
        count ++;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Start fixing this by using only *one* ErrorProvider, there is no advantage to using more than one.  Next, take a look at [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2682478/17034).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a *quick patch*, you can try using *Reflection*:

```
  using System.Reflection;

  ...

  foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) {
    ...
    // Obtain errorProvider[count] via Reflection
    ErrorProvider provider = GetType()
      .GetField($"errorProvider{count}", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
      .GetValue(this) as ErrorProvider;

    provider.SetError(tb, "Please enter a value");
    ... 
  }
```

In case of more elaborated solution, you can organize the `ErrorProvider`s into a collection, say, array:

```
  private ErrorProvider[] m_Providers;

  public MyForm() {
    InitializeComponent();

    //TODO: Think on which providers should be included
    m_Providers = new ErrorProvider[] {
      errorProvider1,
      errorProvider2,  
      errorProvider3,
      errorProvider4,
      errorProvider5,
    };
  }
```

Then you can put

```
  foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) {
    ...
    // Now, errorProviderCount can be taken from the collection
    m_Providers[count - 1].SetError(tb, "Please enter a value");
    ...
  }
```

Comment: would this go into my for loop?

Comment: @Eznx: yes either reflection or array addressing should be within `foreach`; I've edited the answer